# order by clause desc,getting confused between years and months

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to sort warranty in desc order ,but it givces me the months first ,because of the bigger number and then the year on the bottom ,because the number for the year is 1.

```
  SELECT product_name_us product_name_us,
         product_desc_us product_desc_us,
         product_name_ru product_name_ru,
         product_desc_ru product_desc_ru,
         "Warranty",
         in_stock in_stock
    FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'US'
                      THEN
                         COALESCE (TO_CHAR (pd.translated_name), ' ')
                   END
                      AS product_name_us,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'US'
                      THEN
                         CONCAT (SUBSTR (pd.translated_description, 1, 30),
                                 '...')
                   END
                      AS product_desc_us,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'RU'
                      THEN
                         COALESCE (TO_CHAR (pd.translated_name), ' ')
                   END
                      AS product_name_ru,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'RU'
                      THEN
                         CONCAT (SUBSTR (pd.translated_description, 1, 30),
                                 '...')
                   END
                      AS product_desc_ru,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pin.warranty_period = '00-00'
                      THEN
                         'No Warranty'
                      WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) = '00'
                      THEN
                         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) || ' years'
                      WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) = '00'
                      THEN
                         EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) || ' months'
                      WHEN     EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) <> '00'
                           AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) <> '00'
                      THEN
                            EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period)
                         || ' years and '
                         || EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period)
                         || ' months'
                      ELSE
                         'No Warranty'
                   END
                      AS "Warranty",
                   SUM (inv.quantity_on_hand) AS in_stock
              FROM product_descriptions pd
                   INNER JOIN product_information pin
                      ON pd.product_id = pin.product_id
                   INNER JOIN inventories inv ON inv.product_id = pin.product_id
          GROUP BY pd.translated_name,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'US'
                      THEN
                         COALESCE (TO_CHAR (pd.translated_name), ' ')
                   END,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'US'
                      THEN
                         CONCAT (SUBSTR (pd.translated_description, 1, 30),
                                 '...')
                   END,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'RU'
                      THEN
                         COALESCE (TO_CHAR (pd.translated_name), ' ')
                   END,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pd.language_id = 'RU'
                      THEN
                         CONCAT (SUBSTR (pd.translated_description, 1, 30),
                                 '...')
                   END,
                   CASE
                      WHEN pin.warranty_period = '00-00'
                      THEN
                         'No Warranty'
                      WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) = '00'
                      THEN
                         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) || ' years'
                      WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) = '00'
                      THEN
                         EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) || ' months'
                      WHEN     EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period) <> '00'
                           AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period) <> '00'
                      THEN
                            EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pin.warranty_period)
                         || ' years and '
                         || EXTRACT (MONTH FROM pin.warranty_period)
                         || ' months'
                      ELSE
                         'No Warranty'
                   END)
   WHERE     (   product_name_us LIKE '%Monitor%'
              OR product_name_ru LIKE '%Монитор%')
         AND in_stock < 1000
ORDER BY "Warranty" DESC, product_name_us ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to *code* the ORDER BY clause a little bit. Here's an example of how you might try to do that:

```
SQL> with test (warranty) as
  2    (select 'No Warranty' from dual union all
  3     select '13 years'    from dual union all
  4     select '8 months'    from dual union all
  5     select '2 years and 4 months' from dual
  6    )
  7  select warranty
  8  from test
  9  order by case when warranty = 'No Warranty' then 1 end,
 10           case when instr(warranty, 'years') = 0 then 1 else 2 end,
 11           to_number(regexp_substr(warranty, '\d+', 1, 1)),
 12           to_number(regexp_substr(warranty, '\d+', 1, 2))
 13  /

WARRANTY
--------------------
No Warranty
8 months
2 years and 4 months
13 years

SQL>
```

- line 9: "No Warranty" goes first
- line 10: if warranty doesn't contain "years", it should come first (i.e. those are only months)
- line 11: take the first number in "warranty" (i.e. *years*)
- line 12: take the second number in "warranty" (i.e. *months*)

Comment: Works for me (as showed above). Prove that it doesn't, i.e. post your own test case which shows what's going on.

Comment: i did it ,but in a different way ,its working. Thank you!

Comment: To this code i should add row prom another user ,table called products ,the row i need is product_name , i need to use union i know that but i am not sure where and how exactly should i use it